# How to add crypto-js in webpack with angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, cryptojs

I want to use **crypto-js** in angular 2 for encrypt password.Can any one tell me how I add crypto-js plugin in webpack. I don't have any idea about this.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer, that may give you some clue. However this is for angularjs ( angular 1).  This is how my app.js looks like.

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
<other requires>
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

var appRequires = [ngRoute, ngCookies, ngChart];
var app = angular.module('myModule', appRequires)
                 .config{...}; (hidden config goes here)

//  connect controllers services filters
require('./services/couchdbService')(app);
<other controllers and services>
require('./controllers/authCtrl')(app, CryptoJS);
```

Nota BENE, how above I did pass CryptoJS into authCtrl module.
Now lets investigate my authCtrl:

```
module.exports = function(myModule, CryptoJS) {
  myModule.controller('authCtrl',[
   '$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'WebappService',
   function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, WebappService) {
   HERE GOES CONTROLLER BUSINESS LOGIC
   console.log(CryptoJS.SHA256('Taras Vaskiv'));
}]);
}
```

To be honest I had some trouble to apply webpack to angularjs. It doesnt seem that easy as it sounds.